# how to change firefox proxy from addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can not change firefox proxy via the code below:

```
var scope = {};
Components.utils.import("resource://imacros/utils.js", scope);
Components.utils.import("resource://imacros/rijndael.js", scope);
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", scope);
var __loginf = scope.__loginf;
var imns = scope.imns;

var pref = imns.prefsvc.getBranch("network.proxy.");
pref.setCharPref("http", server);
pref.setIntPref("http_port", port);
pref.setCharPref("ssl", server);
pref.setIntPref("ssl_port", port);
pref.setIntPref("type", 1);
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 7):

You should definitely be using the addon-sdk.  Here's a link to their docs for the [preferences service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service) where you can find more info.

Here's what a solution could look like using the addon-sdk.

```
var prefsvc = require("sdk/preferences/service");
prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http", server);
prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http_port", port);
prefsvc.set("network.proxy.ssl", server);
prefsvc.set("network.proxy.ssl_port", port);
prefsvc.set("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

Comment: I would like this to work in an iMacro script I have that uses javascript with iMacro commands. Is there anything special I need to download? Any addons or a specific version of firefox?

Comment: How do you set username/password for the proxy?

Comment: Not sure, I would assume something like ***user:password@server*** for `network.proxy.http` would work as that's how you pass that information in `http`.